# JSON to HTML exclude certain value

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am pulling in some JSON via an API URL that lists events. The JSON looks something like this...

```
{
   "id":1,
   "status":"ok",
   "start":{
      "date":"2021-01-16"
   }
}
```

The simple script to get it into HTML is like this...

```
var url = 'https://api.com/calendar.json';

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var events = data.resultsPage.results.event;
  console.log(events);
  
  events.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    var event_month = moment(array[index].start.date).format('MMM');
    var event_day = moment(array[index].start.date).format('D');
    var event_date = '<div class="event-date">'+ event_month +' '+ event_day +'</div>';    
    var event_performer = array[index].performance[0].artist.displayName;
    var event_venue = array[index].venue.displayName;
    var event_city = array[index].location.city;
    var event_link = array[index].uri;
    var event_details = '<div class="event-location"><div class="event-city">' + event_city + '</div></div><div class="event-venue">' + event_venue + '</div><div class="event-info"><a href="' + event_link + '" target="_blank" class="btn btn--tertiary btn--small">TICKETS</a></div>';
    
    if(event_month != 'Invalid date' && event_day != 'Invalid date') {
      $('.tour-grid').append('<div class="item">' + event_date + event_details + '</div>');
    }
  });
});
```

The problem? I need to EXCLUDE any event with a 'status' marked as 'cancelled'.
Currently, the Javascript pulls in any event no matter of its status.

Is there a way I can modify things to make sure the HTML only outputs events with a status of 'ok' and excludes any event marked as 'cancelled'?

Comment: Look at filtering an object/list in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would be helpful:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var events = data.resultsPage.results.event;
    console.log(events);

    // Initially filter out all the events with status "cancelled" so they won't be rendered
    const filteredEvents = events.filter(event => event.status !== "cancelled");
    // Running on the filtered events
    filteredEvents.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    ...
    });
  });
```